# Telegram bot: wrong currency on invoice

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem with Telegram Payments API.
My local currency is UZS, and I see this currency in invoices on all devices (Android, desktop), except iOS (Telegram client for iOS v5.1).

It's USD on iOS devices, like $100 instead of USZ100.
I checked several payment providers (Sberbank, CLICK and Paycom.uz) - this problem remains with any of them.
Anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Reported this issue to Telegram support - they confirmed it's an error on their side, and it will probably fixed on next release.